# Scaling Images in a Linear Layout Evenly

Tags: android, layout, imageview, android-linearlayout

I have a linear layout that contains 6 images, which span the linear layout horizontally.

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@layout/roundedcorner">
        <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/Icon"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/someImage">
        </ImageView>
        ...
```

The problem is, the first 5 images do not scale and take their pixel width, and the 6th images is scrunched down, because there is not enough space left horizontally.

Is there a way to scale all the images down so they have a uniform look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `android:layout_weight="1"` to each ImageView. If images are of equal size, they will be scaled in the same way then.